# Unable to activate PREACTIVATE_FEATURE protocol feature

Tags: private-blockchain

When I'm using:

```
~$ curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/producer/get_supported_protocol_features -d '{}' | jq
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   212  100   210  100     2   7500     71 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  7851
{
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found",
  "error": {
    "code": 0,
    "name": "exception",
    "what": "unspecified",
    "details": [
      {
        "message": "Unknown Endpoint",
        "file": "http_plugin.cpp",
        "line_number": 380,
        "method": "handle_http_request"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

My nodeos is running and producing blocks, my chain info is:

```
~$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/chain/get_info
{"server_version":"e19afc80","chain_id":"cf057bbfb72640471fd910bcb67639c22df9f92470936cddc1ade0e2f2e7dc4f","head_block_num":17440,"last_irreversible_block_num":17439,"last_irreversible_block_id":"0000441f130c8c2bb256caa162ba36d334bde8a9b6f7e89c79ab1fe3aeb3998a","head_block_id":"0000442041b518fad034a494a7f81edaa342ef7fda2ee6c02f9a636d92ea0c7f","head_block_time":"2020-01-28T07:13:50.500","head_block_producer":"eosio","virtual_block_cpu_limit":200000000,"virtual_block_net_limit":1048576000,"block_cpu_limit":199900,"block_net_limit":1048576,"server_version_string":"v2.0.0","fork_db_head_block_num":17440,"fork_db_head_block_id":"0000442041b518fad034a494a7f81edaa342ef7fda2ee6c02f9a636d92ea0c7f","server_full_version_string":"v2.0.0-e19afc8072219282a7c3fc20e47aa80cb70299e4"}
```

Also,

```
~$ curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8888/v1/chain/get_activated_protocol_features -d '{}' | jq
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    36  100    34  100     2   1259     74 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1440
{
  "activated_protocol_features": []
}
```

What is the problem? What should I do?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the eosio::producer_api_plugin for this to work. You can add it to the config.ini or include it when you start nodeos.

```
# config.ini
plugin = eosio::producer_api_plugin
```

or

```
# nodeos startup params
$ nodeos ... --plugin eosio::producer_api_plugin
```

For reference, details can be found [here](https://eosio.github.io/eos/latest/nodeos/plugins/producer_api_plugin/api-reference/index#operation/get_supported_protocol_features).